# Variable data type

Tags: java, types

I have a class `Calculation` which contains a set of `CalculationResult`.

The `CalculationResult` has a property `String result`. It is a String, but the value can represent a calculated date, boolean, double, ...

So I was thinking of making it so that I can get the result in the right datatype:

```
public Date getAsDate();
public BigDecimal getAsBigDecimal();
...
```

But I'm not sure how I can best implement this.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Are you converting these values to a String? If so why not just keep them around in their original types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you would know what result you expect from your calculation. So you can make a `public class CalculationResult<T>`. Then use, for example:

```
CalculationResult<BigDecimal> result = calculator.getResult(..);
```

Otherwise, if you really have your result as string, always, then the `getAsX` methods can be implemented via methods like `Integer.parseInt(str)`, `new BigDecimal(str)` and `new Date(Long.parseLong(str))` (or using a `DateFormat`). But note that keeping non-text as string is wrong.